# JNIUtil Couldn't find Java class DatabaseModule / Freeze on Splash Screen Error in Titanium Android App

Tags: android, debugging, titanium

While testing an android app developed in Titanium on a variety of different emulators and devices, my app started freezing on the splash screen or simply crashing. I used the ddms application inside android sdk/tools to try to debug the error, and got:

```
JNIUtil Couldn't find Java class: ti/modules/titanium/database/DatabaseModule
```

This was surprising since I hadn't changed any db related code, and never even had to specify that I wanted to load that class. I cleaned the project, restarted the emulator, made new AVDs, etc., without luck.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for others with the same problem, I ran into http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131639/test-package-works-but-signed-one-dies-on-phone and got a clue from a bottom answer. For some reason the Titanium build process was not loading a standard module used in one of my `require(`'d files that handles database stuff. By making a reference to a db at the top of my app.js file, it somehow got the build process to start including the DatabaseModule again.

```
var db = Titanium.Database.open('my_table');
```

Comment: I ran into the problem again even with the above code, which means it's a build problem unrelated to the specific module. My latest solution is to make a change to tiapp.xml (just a space somewhere), and rebuild.